# Swing Jpanel Autofit contents issue

Tags: swing, dynamic, jpanel

I want to achieve following screen design using Swing:

```
-----------------------------------------------
File Type 1:   JTextfield1  Browse Button1  ADD ROW BUTTON
               JTextfield2  Browse Button2

File Type 2:   JTextfield3  Browse Button3  ADD ROW BUTTON
               JTextfield4  Browse Button4

File Type 1:   JTextfield5  Browse Button5  ADD ROW BUTTON
               JTextfield6  Browse Button6
```

On click of ADD ROW BUTTON a new set of JTextfield & Browse Button gets added at appropriate file type section,Each file type section is a Jpanel having miglayout, but the problem is Upon addition of new row the Jpanel does not expand and thus new row shows up only partially and the sections dowm of the screen does not gets pushed down.

How to go about achieving the same.
Please help.

Rajiv Jha

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly understand what you need. But try this example out. It should do what you're looking for.

[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DynaFrame extends JFrame{

    private JPanel basePnl = new JPanel();

    public DynaFrame(){
        this.setTitle("Dynamic panel addition");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //this.setSize(600, 700);
        this.add(getMainPanel());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DynaFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel(){
        basePnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basePnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        basePnl.add(getRowPanel());
        return basePnl;
    }

    public JPanel getRowPanel(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gLayout = new GridLayout();
        gLayout.setColumns(4);
        gLayout.setRows(1);
        pnl.setLayout(gLayout);
        pnl.add(new JLabel("Filetype"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField());
        pnl.add(new JButton("Browse"));
        JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
        addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                basePnl.add(getRowPanel());
                DynaFrame.this.pack();
            }
        });
        pnl.add(addBtn);
        return pnl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What's with `thisFrame = this;`? 2) Swing GUIs should be constructed (and updated) on the EDT.  3) For tips on making screenshots, see the [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) FAQ. 4) An alternate to calling pack() is to use a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : #1) I wanted to do a pack again on the current frame inside the button listener. Thats why i put it there. #2) Will look into this point and refactor the code. #3) I have made a decent screenshot, what suggestion you are trying to say. #4) Agreed. Will try to do refactor that.

Comment: 1) Swap the current code for `DynaFrame.this.pack();` 3)  Yes they're great (got an up-vote from me) but they could be *excellent.*  I was referring to the point in that FAQ that mentions putting the UI over a white BG before taking a screenshot.  (Gets rid of the clutter behind the image.)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : Thanks for your review. Will refactor the answer completely tonight.

Comment: Thanks Bragboy, I think the choice of MigLayout was wrong, but as per your sample code- Using GridLayout things are happening fine. One more help: If I maximize the frame and then add a row it calls pack() and again it comes to original size , How can we prevent window to shrink i have manually resized it?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I refactored the code and the screenshots.